# dynamically populate options in search-box(select) bootstrap jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm following this ( http://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=6.0_6 ) search box tut, but my scenario is bit different. i have countries , cities and location populating dynamically and i want my search box on locations mainly. 
As location populates dynamically the options doesn't get updated in searchbox.
Is there any way that after populating options in location we trigger refresh to search box so that it'll pickup those newly generated options.
Here is the html i'm using:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Countries<span></span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select class="form-control selectpicker chosen-select" name="country_id" id="country_id" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" required>
           <option value="">Select</option>
           <?php  foreach ($countries as $key => $value) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo  $value['name_en']; ?>
           </option>
           <?php } ?>
      </select>
      <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is cities select field

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cities<span></span></label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
       <select class="form-control" name="city_id" id="city_id" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
       </select>
       <span class="help-block"></span>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

This Location field:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Location<span class=""></span></label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="ui-widget">
         <?php echo form_error('location_id'); ?>
         <select id="cars_location" value="<?php echo 
                                            set_select('location_id'); ?>" type="text" class="form-control selectpicker " multiple name="location_id" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" required>
             <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
         </div>
        <div class="omitted_location">

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Now these are the ajax calls from where i'm populating these fields:

```
 window.onload = function(){ 
        $("#country_id").change(function (e) {
            var list    =   '';
            var country_id  =   $(this).val();
            var state = $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url()."Mrsaalaccess/get_record_by_id"; ?>",


                type: "POST",
                data: {id : country_id, get : "cities"},
                dataType: "text"
            });

            state.done(function(msg) {
                if(msg != 'error')
                {
                     $("#city_id").html(msg);
                }
               else{
                    $("#city_id").html(msg);
                }
            });


            state.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });

        $("#city_id").change(function (e) {
            var list    =   '';
            var city_id  =   $(this).val();
            var state = $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url()."Mrsaalaccess/get_location_by_id"; ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : city_id, get : "locations"},
                dataType: "text"
            });


            state.done(function(msg) {
              if(msg != 'error')
                {
                    //Here i'm sending options to locations
                    //which isn't getting populated dynamically
                    $("#cars_location").html(msg); 
                }
               else{
                    $("#location_id").html(msg);
                }
            });

            state.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

                console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );

            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ajax call succeeds and you get new `<option>`s for the `<select>` you  are inserting it right but in order to reflect those updates in bootstrap widget which is a selectpicker in your case, you need to refresh it using `selectpicker('refresh')`.So in case of loaction ..

```
//Here i'm sending options to locations
//which isn't getting populated dynamically
$("#cars_location").html(msg); 
$('#cars_location').selectpicker('refresh'); // <-- add this
```